# Why does "../" on location.href gives different results?

Tags: javascript, maven, alfresco, alfresco-share

I am trying to open a jnlp-file with simple href in javascript from Alfresco Share.
My code:

```
location.href = "../res/components/javawebstart/AEF_JNLP.jnlp";
```

Result on localhost (working):

```
http://localhost:8081/share/res/components/javawebstart/AEF_JNLP.jnlp
```

Result on test environment (not working):

```
http://t1aetest:9080/share/page/context/res/components/javawebstart/AEF_JNLP.jnlp
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`../` means you are going back one level higher than your current directory..

for example :

you are in:

```
com/foo/goo
```

if you say

`../` you will be in foo.

as for your question. use relative path when putting url

for reference click [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/WD-html40-970917/htmlweb.html#h-5.1.2)

Comment: Thank you but why is this working on my local machine and why is the url from the test environment 2 levels higher? where does "page/context/" comes from?

Comment: So I just used ../../../res[...] and it worked. But I dont want to do this everytime I deploy this on the test environment. Is there a try-catch solution to determine which url I shoud use?

Comment: try removing the dots.

Comment: Its working. But is there a universal solution for both environments? Like try-catch?